# Want to use data from database in partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, viewmodel, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I want to use data from my mysql database in my Partial View.

This is my situation:

I have a "tinyint" field in my items table called "item_approved" which is 0 or 1.
 Now I would like to see a number in my partial view that equals all the items that are not approved.

So for example when I have 6 items that have "item_approved" on "0" I get a "6" in my partial view.

I know how I can load the number from my database in my repository but where can I load this? In a controller?

How can I do this the best way?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go and spend some time with the [documentation](http://www.asp.net/mvc)

A high level description would be like:

1. Reference or inject your repository in your controller.
2. In the action that generates the view where you need this number of not approved items; calculate the number and populate a model/viewmodel which is what your view is going to use.
3. Show the number in the view by using your model @Model.NotApprovedItemsCount or whatever you call it.